# Generating same random number onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, onclick, onclicklistener

Sorry if this a duplicate Question, searched high and low and could not find an answer.

I'm trying to generate a new random number on every click. So far, only the first number is random and on every subsequent click nothing happens. I think the getRandomNumber function is only evaluated once and thats why i'm getting the same number.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var index = 0; 

    function getRandomNumber(){
        shuffle = function(o){
            for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
                return o;
        };

        var randorder = shuffle([0,1,2,3,4]);

        return randorder[index++];
    }

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        var gameq = new Array();
        gameq[0] = "Question 1 ?";
        gameq[1] = "Question 2 ?";
        gameq[2] = "Question 3 ?";
        gameq[3] = "Question 4 ?";
        gameq[4] = "Question 5 ?";

        $("#question").replaceWith('<h5>' + gameq[getRandomNumber()] + '</h5>')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply killing your `#question` element at first time. Try to change the last line like this:

```
$("#question").replaceWith('<h5 id="question">' + gameq[getRandomNumber()] + '</h5>');
```

Or may be it will be also good for you:

```
$("#question").html('<h5>' + gameq[getRandomNumber()] + '</h5>');
```

Comment: I would say it's probably better to do this: `$("#question").html(gameq[getRandomNumber()]);`

Comment: I assume you meant `id="question"` instead of `id="#question"`

Comment: @musefan of course , but we don't khow if it is acceptable in OP's case

Comment: @Puuskis 100% , my hands running too fast

Comment: wow, how did i miss that. I went with the second option since that seemed a bit more clean. Thanks

Comment: If using `.html()` (which makes more sense than `.replaceWith()` if you just need to change the content) you don't include the `'<h5>'` and `'</h5>'` because the element is already (presumably) an h5.